# Swift 2 - Protocol conforming to Equatable issue

Tags: ios, swift2

I have an issue with a protocol I've defined below. I've got two requirements:

1. I'd like to be able to use the protocol `Peer` as a type in other classes while keeping the concrete class private.
2. I'd like to store the protocol in an array and be able to determine the index of an instance.

In order to satisfy the second point, I need to make the protocol conform to the `Equatable` protocol. But when I do that, I can no longer use `Peer` as a type, since it needs to be treated as a generic. This means I cannot have the concrete implementation private anymore, and requirement 1 is broken.

Wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem and gotten around it somehow. Maybe I'm misinterpreting the error I'm getting at `indexOf`...

`Group.swift`

```
import Foundation

class Group {
    var peers = [Peer]()

    init() {
        peers.append(PeerFactory.buildPeer("Buddy"))
    }

    func findPeer(peer: Peer) -> Bool {
        if let index = peers.indexOf(peer) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

`Peer.swift`

```
import Foundation

protocol Peer {
    var name: String { get }
}

class PeerFactory {
    static func buildPeer(name: String) -> Peer {
        return SimplePeer(name: name)
    }
}

private class SimplePeer: Peer {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Error at `indexOf` if `Peer` is *not* `Equatable`:

```
cannot convert value of type 'Peer' to expected argument type '@noescape (Peer) throws -> Bool'
```

Comment: Array-of-protocol can be problematic. Did you watch the WWDC 2015 video on protocol-based Swift programming?

Comment: I watched it a few months ago. I'll rematch it and see if it gives me any clues.

Comment: The problem of what it can mean for an array of protocol-adopters to be equatable is at the very heart of the video. But be warned: array-of-protocol is problematic. :)

Comment: See my (unanswered) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found a solution to get around the `Equatable` requirement by extending `CollectionType` to define a new `indexOf` for elements are of `Peer` type, which takes advantage of the *other* closure-based `indexOf`. This is essentially a convenience function which saves me from using the closure `indexOf` directly. Code below:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == Peer {
    func indexOf(element: Generator.Element) -> Index? {
        return indexOf({ $0.name == element.name })
    }
}
```

This of course assumes everything I need to test equality can be obtained from the `Peer` protocol (which is true for my specific use case).

**EDIT:** Update for Swift 3:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Peer {
    func indexOf(element: Iterator.Element) -> Index? {
        return index(where: { $0.name == element.name })
    }
}
```

Comment: In the general case, you'd need to write your own extension to handle your protocol for anything that requires the type to implement Equatable, and then manually perform an equality check.

Comment: This answer is basically the solution given in the WWDC 2015 video that I advised you to watch, is it not?

Comment: No not exactly. They solve the `Equatable Drawable` issue by defining an `isEqual` method in the protocol, and then they wrote a protocol extension for all classes that are both `Drawable` and `Equatable` to handle the comparison. What I'm doing here is avoiding `Equatable` completely for my specific need of the `indexOf` method. This is the video I'm referencing, with the solution starting at 38:30: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/

Comment: Okay, well, for people who don't see that that's the same idea, they don't see that that's the same idea. :)

Comment: Swift 3 does not seems happy with this solution. Is there an updated one ?

Comment: Let me take a look at updating it tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use public super class, so the class can conform to `Equatable`

```
class Peer: Equatable {
    // Read-only computed property so you can override.
    // If no need to override, you can simply declare a stored property 
    var name: String {
        get {
            fatalError("Should not call Base")
        }
    }

    // should only be called from subclass
    private init() {}
}

private class SimplePeer: Peer {
    override var name: String {
        get {
            return _name
        }
    }

    let _name: String

    init(name: String) {
        _name = name
        super.init()
    }
}

func == (lhs: Peer, rhs: Peer) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

class PeerFactory {
    static func buildPeer(name: String) -> Peer {
        return SimplePeer(name: name)
    }
}
```

Comment: That works as well, although the necessary fatalError is a bit of a design smell. This might be a more viable option if I find that there's a lot of functions with Equatable requirements that I need to rewrite for my protocol.